# A question related to a smooth function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, smooth-functions

Suppose $g \in C^{1}[0,1]$ such that
$$\int_{0}^{1}|g'(t)|^2\:dt \leq R$$
for some constant $R$.

I am interested in proving that for all $a,b \in [0,1]$,
$$|g(a)-g(b)|\leq \sqrt{R}|a-b|^{1/2}.$$

I tried using the Mean Value Theorem to show that
$$|g(a)-g(b)|\leq \sqrt{R}|a-b|$$
but it's missing $|a-b|^{1/2}$.

Any hint or help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use $g(b) - g(a) = \int_{a}^{b}g'(t)\,dt$ and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $f(t)=\dfrac{g(t)}{\sqrt{R}}$. Then we have by the assumption that

$\int_{0}^{1}|f'(t)|^{2}dt\leq\,1$. Take $a<b$ in $[0,1]$. Then

$f(b)-f(a)=\int_{a}^{b}f'(t)dt$ and hence

$|f(b)-f(a)|\leq\,\int_{a}^{b}|f'(t)|dt$. Now we use the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality for $F(t)=|f'(t)|$ and $G(t)=1$ and we get:

$\int_{a}^{b}|f'(t)|dt\,\leq\,(\int_{a}^{b}|f'(t)|^{2}dt)^{1/2}(b-a)^{1/2}$$\leq\,\int_{0}^{1}|f'(t)|^{2}dt$$(b-a)^{1/2}$$\leq\,(b-a)^{1/2}$.

Therefore we get $|\dfrac{g(b)}{\sqrt{R}}-\dfrac{g(a)}{\sqrt{R}}|\,\leq\,(b-a)^{1/2}$

which implies $|g(b)-g(a)|\leq\,\sqrt{R}(b-a)^{1/2}$